# In the sealed deck mode of Magic 2014, are the slots for decks separate or do they feed to the same pool?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

I just want to know if the decks are infinitely expandable, limited only by the money you spend or does each "slot" only have a limited number of boosters for it? I've owned all the other DOPs but I am hesitant to have a repeat of my Magic Online purchase. What I had liked about the previous DOPs was that I spent a contained amount of money and remained competitive ($10 for the base, $5 for the expansion, 3 $2 pack expansions for a total of $21). Is that still going to be true with this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The card pool of each slot is limited to the six boosters you start with plus the three boosters you unlock by beating the first, third and fifth opponent. The extra slots are there because you can't reset the slots. Once you started a sealed campaign the cards you get are locked in and not changeable. So the only thing the extra slots give you is a chance at a better sealed pool.